# Opening webpage from inside a script

Tags: c#, html

I created a Windows C# script that generates HTML files, then builds a webpage with links to those HTML files (reportName contains the path and name of the final webpage).

The script is executed from a webpage. After the reportName webpage is created, I want to open the new reportName webpage from the script. At the end of the script I have the following:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Added for testing
var openPage = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = reportName
};
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openPage);
```

When I execute the script either manually or through a webpage, it creates all the files including the last one (reportName) containing all the links.

The problem I have has to do with opening the final webpage for reportName. If I execute the script manually, it opens the reportName webpage, but if I do it from a browser (Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge, Internet Explorer), it does not open the new webpage.

I am not finding any errors in the Windows logs or any new processes in the [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)) when I click to execute the script from the webpage.

Since it happens with four different browsers, I'm leaning towards it being a scripting issue, but I could also be a security issue with Windows. I've tried adding the link in the webpage to auto open after calling the script, but it tries to open the reportName page before the script is finished creating it.

Any suggestions?

I have also tried both of the following without any error codes:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(newpathName)
{
  UseShellExecute = true
};
p.Start();


System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
try {
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  process.StartInfo.FileName = newpathName;
  process.Start();
} catch(Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

But if I use the following I do get a "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"

```
system.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Chrome", Uri.EscapeDataString(reportName));
```

Comment: C# does not run in a browser so you are running a web server.  Are you saying when it runs in a web server it does not work?  That means the service account associated with the web server does not have rights to access the file.  You need to adjust your security settings.

Comment: Think about your design and the result.  If a web browser could run a local script then any web page you went to could take over your machine and get all your local data etc.  The security is a night mare.  This is why it does not work by default.  If you create a web page that does this it will be a security hole and you will be hacked.  I expect this is not something you want to happen.  You might consider a different design.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you are running a local exe from web page?  There is no browser in the universe that should let you do that.  It is a security nightmare (as I describe above)

Comment: If you want to use HTML and javascript to write an application or local program there are a number of platforms that support that -- but not a web browser.

Comment: Take a look at Electron or Tauri -- or the most simple node.js

Comment: The remote Windows server uses ajax for the web server. I compiled my script into a stand-alone exe and execute it from the remote or local browser using a js script. The compiled C# script reads several different files along with the application database and creates a series of reports. The reports are placed into a HTML folder on the server and then the final page is created that has links to each of the HTML report files. When I click on the button on the webpage either on the server or on my remote computer, the script fully executes with the exception of opening the new browser window.

Comment: AJAX is a method of calling web services -- I'm not sure what has to do with anything.  You also say server and remote -- the server and remote mean the same thing as far as I know.  What you are describing does not make sense to me.  What is the use case -- how is this going to be used and why can't it just be a C# application.

Comment: The server is a "device" that is used for a single application. Most people have the device tucked away in a closet and access it through a webpage on a personal device. The webserver allows management and viewing of a type of infrastructure from a web browser. The product on the device allows customization from end users either for personal or commercial use. I have created several other complied C# applications that I can run from clicking on a button on the products web page on my personal computer but I cannot get a new webpage to spawn from the script.

Comment: _" but if I do it from a browser (Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge, Internet Explorer) it does not open the new webpage. ... I am not finding any errors in the Windows logs..."_, Did you check the console log for whichever browser you try to use, if there are script errors you should see them in the console log?

Comment: quaabaam, I didn't think about checking out the console log for the browser. Although I think I just figured out a non c# workaround. I created another <script> section for AjaxPost("action=run_script_command& that runs a second vb script that pauses for 2 seconds then opens the new webpage. It appears to work but I would rather have it built into my c# script. I will get back to this issue tomorrow since I need to take get out of here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Last night I realized my mistake. I was so fixated on what I was developing on the server end that I neglected the fact that the local browser is not going to see any of it until some action happens on the local webpage. Yes, it is a dummy mistake, but sometimes I need to talk things through to understand what is happening.

It appears what is required is a one second pause after the new page is created, and then a redirect is what is needed. The pause will give the server time to create the page.

Comment: In other words, a timing issue?